# Compile proftpd and include a library copy inside the installation directory

Tags: c++, mysql, linux, gcc, aix

I do already ask a quiet [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193787/static-compilation-of-proftpd-on-aix) but in fact I now change my mind.
Id like like to compile proftpd and add a copy of the library it uses to the choosen installation directory.
Let's say I define a prefix in my compilation like:

```
/usr/local/proftpd
```

Under this directory I would like to find and use those directories only :

```
./lib
./usr/lib
./usr/bin
./usr/.....
./etc
./var/log/proftpd
./bin
./sbin
./and others I will not put the whole list
```

So the idea is after I have all libraries and config file in my main directory I could `tar` it and send it on another server with the same OS and without installing all the dependencies of protfpd I could use it.
I know it does sound like a windows installer not using shared library but that's in fact exactly what I'm trying to accomplish.

So far I have manage to compile it on AIX using this command line:
`./configure --with-modules=mod_tls:mod_sql:mod_sql_mysql:mod_sql_passwd:mod_sftp:mod_sftp_sql --without-getopt --enable-openssl --with-includes=/opt/freeware/include:/opt/freeware/include/mysql/mysql/:/home/poney2/src_proftpd/libmath_header/ --with-libraries=/opt/freeware/lib:/opt/freeware/lib/mysql/mysql/:/home/poney2/src_proftpd/libmath_lib --prefix=/home/poney/proftpd_bin --exec-prefix=/home/poney/proftpd_bin/proftpd`

Before trying to ask me why I'm doing so, it's because I have to compile proftpd on IBM AIX with almost all modules and this is not available on the IBM rpm binary repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of this `LDFLAG`

```
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-blibpath:/a/new/lib/path"
```

where `/a/new/lib/path` contains all your library does work with Xlc and Gcc compiler.